# Strip all header in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, header

We have a mvc action that will send data to a embedded device, but would like it not to send any header information. Is this at all possible with a ActionFilter and how?

Comment: Do you mean omitting HTTP-headers? No content-type, no content-size, no nothing?

Comment: yip... as much as possible without stuffing around with modules etc.

Comment: mvc sucks... rather use old faithfull php anyday...

Comment: Eventually moved this logic over to a Python socket server and the base web app to PHP. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its seems quite tricky to do this without having to add a Module to IIS which will strip the headers... So no go..